# Spark 2.2.0 S3 Performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I'm in the process of moving my code from the test lab cluster to a EC2 cluster. I set it up using `flintrock` and I'm running "vanilla" `Spark 2.2.0` .
At the moment the cluster has 4 `c3.2xlarge` nodes (1 master, 3 Worker)

I want to process a large set of files with each file in itself beeing relatively large (around 1 GB). In my code I slice the number of files up into chunks. In the "lab" I found that the performance for a  8vCPU 13G System peaks at about 32 files per chunk and save the result to a parquet. On EC2 with 3 workers I translated this to 96 chunks which results in 192 task.  Now I'm confronted with bad S3 performance. I get the following error:

```
17/09/09 03:45:33 INFO AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:686)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:488)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:384)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.copyObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1507)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyCallable.copyInOneChunk(CopyCallable.java:143)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyCallable.call(CopyCallable.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.copy(CopyMonitor.java:189)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.call(CopyMonitor.java:134)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.call(CopyMonitor.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I followed this guide: https://hortonworks.github.io/hdp-aws/s3-performance/

I change the sparkconf setup to this:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appname)\
.setMaster(master)\
.set('spark.executor.memory','13g')\
.set('spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version','2')\
.set('fs.s3a.fast.upload','true')\
.set('fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer','disk')\
.set('fs.s3a.buffer.dir','/tmp/s3a')
```

and save the parquet with s3a like this:

```
df.write.parquet('s3a://mybucket/result_parquet')
```

Also I reduced the chunk size to 48 (16 per instance). The errors become less but still some come up. But now performance is decreased because of the reduced chunk size.

Now I'm wondering:

a) Did I configure `SparkConf()` correctly? The errors where only significantly reduced after I reduced the chunk size.

b) If the S3 performance is limited by "requests" per EC2 Instance. So if I instead of 3 medium instances I get 6 smaller would S3 then be able to handle 192 parquet write tasks better just because they come from more Instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your bandwidth to S3 depends on the VM type you rent: the better the network, the more bandwidth.
2. You are throttled for writing to a specific bucket or shard of a bucket, where S3 will send a 503 response back for a client to handle.
3. But what you are seeing here is surfacing as a Socket Exception; looks like the AWS xfer manager isn't handling it.

If this is happening at task commit, it's because s3a mimics rename() with copy + delete, and the output committer expects rename to be an O(1) atomic operation, rather than a slow one. More critically, that mimic of rename depends on listing files in S3, and, because s3 is eventually consistent, can miss files in the listing. *you will lose data*

Unless you have a consistency layer atop S3 (s3mper, s3guard), you should be committing to local HDFS for any sequence of queries, copying up to S3 when you have the final work. Or, if you have time on your hands, help test HADOOP-13786, which adds the 0-rename-commit

Comment: Thanks for the input. I probably will create a HDFS cache. One question tough when I copy stuff from the HFDS to S3 is there still a risk to lose data?

Comment: no: apps get a consistent listing of the HDFS data, which they use to copy up